# Getting static value after deserialization

Tags: java

Please clear my understanding why I am getting of value of company after deserialization. I know "Statics are implicitly transient, so we don't need to declare them as such."

```
    class Employee implements Serializable {
        String name;
        static String company = "My Company";

        public Employee(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    public class Test8 {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            Employee e = new Employee("John");
            serializeObject(e);// assume serialize works fine
            Employee e1 = deserializeObject(); // assume deserialize works fine
            System.out.println(e1.name + " " + e1.company);
        }

   public static void serializeObject(Employee e) throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Test8.cert");
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(e);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
    }

    public static Employee deserializeObject() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("Test8.cert");
        ObjectInputStream oos = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        return (Employee) oos.readObject();
    }


    }
```

Comment: What is `serializeObject()` and `deserializeObject()`?

Comment: added both the methods.

Comment: Because you're in the same JVM, so the class isn't re-initialized.

Comment: If they're implicitly transients, then they're not serialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value of static field `company` was set first time you used `Employee` class. In your case it would be in line:

```
Employee e = new Employee("John");
```

This value didn't change since it wasn't serialized and deserialized so it stayed the same, which means

```
System.out.println(e1.name + " " + e1.company);
```

prints `John My Company`.

---

But even if you remove lines

```
Employee e = new Employee("John");
serializeObject(e);
```

from your code, and invoke only

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Employee e1 = deserializeObject(); // assume deserialize works fine
    System.out.println(e1.name + " " + e1.company);
}
```

`Employee` class will still be loaded inside `deserializeObject` (by `oos.readObject()` method) so its static fields will also be properly initialized to its default values.

Comment: The value "My Company" will not serialized, in the deserialization process, new Employee Object will be created (that is different from what we have serialized)and have no value for company;
then it should print null.

Comment: It seems that you are confusing "*and have no value for company*". You seem to know that `static` is implicitly `transient` which means it is not serialized and deserialized. Because of that lack of value doesn't mean that value *will be set to `null`*, but that value *will not be modified*. Try adding static block to your `Employee` class like `static{System.out.println("loading Employee");}`. You will see that even if your code will only be deserialization `readObject` will internally load `Employee` class, which means it will also initialize its static fields making `company = "My Company"`